# Cannot type dash (-) on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot type this character (-) on visual studio code. I get a pop-up every time saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comments')". I just started a new project and haven't written any code as of yet.

So I don't get why I cannot write a dash/hyphen when it always has worked until know. Let me know if you have a solution to this problem.

Here is my settings.json in vs code.

```
{
"tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [

]
```

}

Comment: Maybe it's a keyboard shortcut ? Try checking your keybindings if it's there

Comment: Can you share your `settings.json`?

Comment: I would try reinstalling or resetting all settings

Comment: Not keybindings, because it has worked before but not now. It could be something I'm missing. I have edited in the settings.json file

Comment: What extensions do you have loaded when it happens?

Comment: How do you check that?

Comment: I have tried resetting vs code. Also reset the setting.json. Still doesn't work. Really weird.

Comment: Hey, did you fix this. I am having same issue in @popos since ever. I have to literally copy - from somewhere else. The weird thing is it is only VS Code .... in terminal it works fine. Tried all the solutions found on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Open

> Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting

with ctrl+shift+p and press the dash (-) symbol after then you may can see your problem.

My problem was like that:

```
2024-01-26 15:07:10.553 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-01-26 15:07:10.554 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [Equal]
2024-01-26 15:07:10.554 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched workbench.panel.reply.view.toggleVisibility, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-01-26 15:07:10.554 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Equal, keyCode: 189, key: -
2024-01-26 15:07:10.555 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Equal, keyCode: 88 ('-')
2024-01-26 15:07:10.556 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [Equal]
2024-01-26 15:07:10.556 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 5 keybinding entries, matched workbench.panel.reply.view.toggleVisibility, when: no when condition, source: user.
2024-01-26 15:07:10.556 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command workbench.panel.repl.view.toggleVisibility.
```

I opened the Keyboard shortcuts settings, looked up that property workbench.panel.repl.view.toggleVisibility
I figured out the property has a few defined features. I reset all of the other defined dash(-) properties and it fixed. The dash(-) type is enable for now.